# error purr package or namespace loading failed for purr package was installed before r 4.0.0

Tags: r, purrr

i am working on a college server, where there is no internet. so i installed packages from archive folder.

I try to use purr, but the interface show me that error:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘purr’:
package ‘purr’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it

Comment: purrr, with 3 r's.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is confusing but it's saying the package is already compiled for an earlier version of R. (That's what the option "win.binary" means). R 4.0 and earlier binaries are not compatible because of updated compilers and build tools.

Option 1:

You'll need to install the package from source, which likely means fresh installing R tools (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) or you'll need to use a version that is pre-built for R 4.0 or later.
Installing R (and RStudio and packages) without active internet connection is possible, if a bit of a nuisance since it need to update library.
To allow us to give you a more specific answer please specify two things:

1: Your OS?

2: do you have admin rights on the computer?

But what is required is in principle to download R and RStudio installers to a flash disk, together with the package archives from CRAN in *.tar.gz format. These can be installed from RStudio via Tools - Install Packages... & picking the Package Archive drop down instead of the default CRAN option.

Option [2:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63647828/15021889)

You need to remove all previous installations of R, and their associated directories. Then all packages need to be reinstalled under the new version (4.0).

check your package library path

```
.libPaths()
```

grab old packages names

```
old_packages <- installed.packages(lib.loc = "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library")
old_packages <- as.data.frame(old_packages)
list.of.packages <- unlist(old_packages$Package)
```

remove old packages

```
remove.packages( installed.packages( priority = "NA" )[,1] )
```

reinstall all packages

```
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
lapply(list.of.packages,function(x){library(x,character.only=TRUE)})
```

Option 3:

It is simple and effective. You need to make a small partition in a PC with internet (OS must be the same in both machines) and just install r base, R studio, and other desired libraries in the same partition. Now copy the partition in any external drive using gparted and paste the same partition in the machine which have no internet.

(Please check how to use gparted)

Comment: many thanks for your prompt reply and response. i have windows operting system. i dont have admin right but i can ask my admin guy to do it